# I want to make mro_id column values are links to a particular action using ignited datatables

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

How make values as links in ignited datatables? How to make it easy?

Controller

```
 function index()
    {


        $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table id="big_table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="mytable">' );
        $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 

        $this->table->set_heading('First Name','Last Name','Email');

        $this->load->view('subscriber_view');
    }
function datatable()
    {

        $this->datatables
        ->select("mro_id,mro_name,mctg_name,mctg_id")
        ->from('jil_mroproducts')
        ->join('jil_mrocategory', 'jil_mroproducts.mro_category=jil_mrocategory.mctg_id', 'INNER')
        ->unset_column('mro_id');
         echo $this->datatables->generate();        

    }
```

Comment: Please do not add requests for urgency, ASAP, deadlines, or similar in your posts. Questions here, as per every other volunteer-driven forum on the internet, are of equal priority.

Comment: Ok i wil careful asking question.Thank you so much for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->datatables->edit_column('mro_id', '<a href="controller/method/$1">$2</a>', 'mro_id, mro_name');
```

---

`$1` links to `mro_id`

and

`$2` links to `mro_name`

---

Read this [`$this->datatables->edit_column($column, $content, $match_replacement);`](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/wiki/Function-Reference#this-datatables-edit_columncolumn-content-match_replacement)

Comment: no,not any errors ,but link is not getting, i wil check it once more,may be its my fault

Comment: Thank you so muchhh dearrrr... its worked well. You really helped me

Comment: Thanks for helping me.from morning , i asked about datatable in stackoverflow,but somebody put downvote for me :( so i deleted that questions. i tried many code for server side datatables. Is ignited table process fast for huge amount of data?

Comment: @Angel i have used that for few amount of data. Most nearly 550. you need to load it and check, I think its works

Comment: i used 2500 data ,its works.our tables are for ecommerce purpose.so large amount of records are there

Comment: Will suggest you some thing. duplicate current database and  load it with huge number of data. (duplicate your exisitng data in table) and check. This what we call Load testing

Comment: Is there any code in codeigniter to duplicate table data?

Comment: @Angel i dont know about that. Export tabale data to CSV and change id filed and insert back to it

Comment: Welcome back my friend

Comment: @Abdulla ,Friend are you here?

Comment: @Angel ya. Whats the matter

Comment: @Abdulla I had an issue,mysql and mysqli in datatable library file,its solved

Comment: @Abdulla i have a css issue. do you know how make option values inside a select box in black color.when i integrate datatable to my project,the select numbers 10,50,100 etc are gone white color .

Comment: There is possible answers. Check in stack. I saw same. Im now on mobile so hard to provide link. Or post it has new Q

Comment: @Abdulla i want a help in datatable

Comment: What kind of help?? Explain please

Comment: @Abdulla Please look my question.can u solve it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646188/i-want-to-convert-this-query-in-codeigniter-to-ignited-datatable-query